# How cache all page before user visit website in cakephp

Tags: caching, cakephp

how to cache all page before user visit my website. 
You can suggest i how to make that.
Please more specify because i dont know much about cache, i only know use it in cakephp.

Comment: Um... the cache will have to be refreshed at some point, so some user will have to visit an uncached page at some point. Why do you want to "pre-create" all possible cache files?

Comment: i want "pre-create" cache, in 2 hour, it will auto create cache files. I dont want first user wait to load uncached web longer litle.

Comment: How long can the initial uncached page possibly take to load? If your site is so slow that it's only usable in cached form, you're doing something wrong. Also, there may be a huge number of possible URLs you may need to cache; for example if you're using any sort of pagination there are countless possible permutations for a URL, most of which will probably never be seen by any user.

Comment: I think you're worrying about nothing. One user getting marginally slower response out of the six billion who will visit your site is a small percentage.

Comment: yes, now i think as this, too ><

Comment: 'one out of six billion', wow! If we are so lucky :)

Answer (score 2):

This might be just what you are looking for: 
https://github.com/mcurry/html_cache

It will serve up an html cached version of a page without hitting cakephp or even php. This will make it thousands of times faster than cake. See this link as well, item #4.
http://www.pseudocoder.com/archives/2009/03/17/8-ways-to-speed-up-cakephp-apps/

Comment: Of course, you have to invalidate the cache yourself as stated above.

Comment: "thousands of times faster than cake" has little relevance when most of the time goes in latency.